# Fake a Media Item for Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, fakedb

Is possible to autogenerate a Media "element" ?

I am trying to do this

```
mediaProvider.GetMedia(Arg.Is<Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem>(i => i.ID == mediaItemId)).Returns(Arg.Any<Media>());
```

but this can apparently not be done?
I don't care about what the content of the Media, it just not allowed to be empty,
I would very much like to avoid defined the media, for reusability purpose..

I was in the Sitecore chat pointed towards using AutoFixture, but I'm not quite sure how to use it here and whether it creates a specific instance of the Media, and not a random one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package from Sitecore.FakeDb that integrates with AutoFixture to generate items on the fly. The Nuget package is Sitecore.FakeDb.AutoFixture

https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/wiki/AutoFixture-Samples

After you generate the item, then you can assign the item as a MediaItem https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/wiki/Media

A very quick sample walkthrough will be something like:

```
[Fact]
public void CreateItemInstance()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoDbCustomization()).Customize(new AutoContentItemCustomization()); ;
    var item = fixture.Create<Item>();
    var database = fixture.Create<Database>();

    Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem(database.GetItem(item.ID));

  // Continue doing the rest
}
```